# Where can I find the data for my DR in GT Sport?

Tags: gran-turismo-sport

I've found my Driver's rating (DR) on [Kudos Prime](https://www.kudosprime.com), but I can't find the original information. When I check my official profile, I only see the DR letter with a little bar under it.

Is there any place where I can find the actual number with my DR?

Comment: A better link to use is http://www.kudosprime.com/gts/stats.php?profile=search

Comment: There was some issue with my profile, eventually it appeared on the site.